# I want to go to a file and pick up a values based on file name and keyword present in my file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting, so i need all your help to achieve my goal. I have a file named input.csv which consists of data like shown below,

```
G22822 277 OR2
G22822 329 OR9
G22940 286 OR3
G22940 412 OR7
G25365 289 OR3
```

Now, `OR2`, `OR9`, `OR3`, `OR7` and `OR3` are also different files with the name as `al_or2.cap`, `al_or9.cap`, `al_or3.cap`, `al_or7.cap` and `al_or3.cap` in different path. The data present in these cap files are like shown below,

**In al_or2.cap:**

```
277 ASCII GRP 184578924
102 ASCII GRP 754815923
```

**In al_or9.cap:**

```
981 ASCII GRP 542189353
329 ASCII GRP 158203981
```

Like wise data present in all cap files.

If you see first line in input.csv(G22822 277 OR2) as data mentioned i need to go to al_or2.cap and search for keyword 277 and print G22822 and 542189353(G22822 present in input.csv and 542189353 present in al_or2.cap).

Then, for this G22822 329 OR9 i need to go to al_or9.cap and print G22822 and 158203981.

**My required output like:**

```
G22822 184578924
G22822 158203981 and so on..
```

Please help help me to achieve my goal.

Comment: `G22822 277 OR2` is not `.csv` (comma-separated-values). Did you mean space-separated-values (or did you remove the commas?) And does what you are calling `csv` always have 3-fields?

Comment: What if the keyword isn't present in the second file?

Comment: Yes they are space separated values, and always having 3 fields in it. @david

Comment: If keyword not present then i don't want to print it @ shawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data you presented is accurate, and not knowing your directory structure, here's a little something

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a b c
do
  awk -v a=$a -v b=$b  'b==$1{printf "%s %s\n", a, $4}' tmp/al_$(echo $c | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]').cap
done < input.csv
```

Saving that as `karthik.sh`, having saved the first two lines of your input.csv,  having created a subdirectory tmp with the files `al_or2.cap` and `al_or9.cap` in it, and running `./karthik.sh` I get the following output:

```
./karthik.sh 
G22822 184578924
G22822 158203981
```

Comment: If he is not running bash (as the question is tagged `"shell"`, then there will be problems with `${c,,}` which is a bashism. (better to use `tr` until you know for sure)

Comment: Fair comment, modifying post accordingly; thanks! :)

Comment: Sure -- I've been caught by that more than once `:)`

Comment: Dude, One more question what if i need to print 277 and OR2  as well. i.e, (G22822 184578924 277 OR2)

Comment: That makes the awk statement a little longer.  `awk -v a=$a -v b=$b -vc=$c  'b==$1{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", a, $4, b, c}' tmp/al_$(echo $c | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]').cap`

Answer (score 1):

If your original file has 3-fields and your data files (e.g. `al_or2.cap`, etc..) all have 4-fields, you can use a single call to `awk` and the builtin functions `tolower`, `sprintf`, `getline` and `split` to form the filename, read the corresponding file and output the results in your desired order as follows:

```
awk '
{   lwr = tolower($3)
    str = sprintf ("al_%s.cap", lwr)
    while (getline line < str > 0) {
        split (line, a, " ", seps)
        if (a[1] == $2)
            print $1,a[4]
    }
}' file
```

**Files Present**

```
$ cat file
G22822 277 OR2
G22822 329 OR9
G22940 286 OR3
G22940 412 OR7
G25365 289 OR3

$ cat al_or2.cap
277 ASCII GRP 184578924
102 ASCII GRP 754815923

$ cat al_or9.cap
981 ASCII GRP 542189353
329 ASCII GRP 158203981
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
> {   lwr = tolower($3)
>     str = sprintf ("al_%s.cap", lwr)
>     while (getline line < str > 0) {
>         split (line, a, " ", seps)
>         if (a[1] == $2)
>             print $1,a[4]
>     }
> }' file
G22822 184578924
G22822 158203981
```

**Creating a Simple `awk` Script**

If you would like to create an `awk-script` from the above, you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    lwr = tolower($3)
    str = sprintf ("al_%s.cap", lwr)
    while (getline line < str > 0) {
        split (line, a, " ", seps)
        if (a[1] == $2)
            print $1,a[4]
    }
}
```

Now all you need do is to save the file and make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x myscript.awk`, and then

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./myscript.awk file
G22822 184578924
G22822 158203981
```